# Math functions in Racket

Tags: functional-programming, racket

I'm new in Racket programming. How can I use built in math functions? Example factorial? In first line I inserted  #lang racket/base but it not imported math functions. When I use factorial function I have error:
`factorial: unbound identifier in: factorial`

Thank you for help me.

Comment: This factorial? https://docs.racket-lang.org/math/number-theory.html?q=factorial#%28def._%28%28lib._math%2Fnumber-theory..rkt%29._factorial%29%29. The top of the page says you need to add `(require math/number-theory)` at the top of your program (but after `#lang racket/base`) in order to use that function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `racket/base` language is fairly bare bones, and doesn't provide many math functions. The `racket` language is a bit bigger, although still doesn't have `factorial` in particular. However, the `math` library does have factorial. So you can always `require` it on top of whatever language you use. As such, you will end up with a program like:

```
#lang racket
(require math)

(factorial 5) ; => 120
```

Comment: Hey there! I've got a small question on top of what was already asked, Racket has a `racket/math` module that is automatically imported when `#lang racket` is present. Wouldn't it be better if `math-lib` was part of `racket/math`? Or is it separate so that it may receive updates regardless of the Racket version?